# Can the GPU issue in 2011 Macbook Pros be latent?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, graphics, gpu, repair

How permanent is the GPU defect in 2011-2013 MacBook Pros? Suppose one tests a used Macbook Pro by running a few random programs for ten minutes. Is it possible that the seller would have experienced the problem and not have declared it, and that the buyer would see no symptom, perhaps until the machine gets really warm? The problem is supposedly a heat dissipation problem. Could it be latent—in the sense that it would appear and disappear—or does it become always visible once it manifests?

In particular, it appears that the user [can](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110647/is-there-a-way-to-view-and-control-the-powerstate-of-the-discrete-gpu-on-a-2011) switch from the AMD to the Intel GPU. If that's the case, how can I guard against a seller having activated the Intel GPU to conceal a problem with the AMD GPU?

Notes:

- Apple's [repair program](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) lapsed.
- A.S.E. Q&As on the issue in question: [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159025/macbook-pro-late-2011-had-gpu-problems), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88734/2011-macbook-pro-gpu-dying)

Comment: No model of MacBook lets you switch between GPUs. Do you mean MacBook Pro?

Comment: @MikeScott I wasn't specific. Yes, thanks. The GPU problem is limited to AMD and to Macbook Pros. Edited the question.

Comment: You can't disable the GPU in El Cap or Sierra without disabling SIP.  Install macOS on a USB drive and *bypass* the internal drive if you can't be certain SIP is enabled or not.    If this is really a concern, also  run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  There are no kexts to bypass in AHT.

Comment: For those (like myself a minute ago) who were not keeping up: SIP stands for System Integrity Protection.  https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204899  Still trying to figure out why I need to install ElCapitan/Sierra on USB if ElCapitan/Sierra is already installed. Wouldn't it be sufficient to determine if SIP is enabled?

Comment: If you are unsure of what changes the seller made (like disabling SIP), you use an external drive that you provide so you can be sure of the OS environment.  Since there's no way to *physically* disable a GPU, a clean OS you source will ensure you're evaluating the machine on your terms.

Comment: @Allan I see. Thanks. Does macOS guarantee that if it's installed on machine A, it will run on machine B, even if the specs of the two machines are completely different? You're not suggesting that I would take *two* USB drives and install the stock (Apple released) OS from one to the other on the target machine. That'd be asking for too much patience.

Comment: A single USB will be fine - if you know how to check if SIP is enabled/disabled, then you don't have to do that.

Comment: That advice with SIP disabled or not is almost useless. You can disable SIP completely, make your changes – like disabling AMD chip – re-eanble SIP. Then the SIP status gets you no valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

The failing GPUs in these units are **all** subject to failure in a timeframe most would call premature. This is because the the cooling system and the generation of and the vulnerability to heat of the AMD chips are mismatched. All official Apple repairs were nothing more than swapping out the entire logic board and replacing it with the exact same thing, spec wise. Above normal room temperature and really stressing the GPU with 3D rendering while a second monitor is plugged in (getting even more heat from the thunderbolt chips) is a surefire way to further shorten the lifetime of the AMD chips.

Investing into a used machine from 2011 with AMD chips inside is a bad idea unless it is really cheap. That is because the issues can be indeed *latent in the early stages.* The problem starts with different symptoms and in different stages, some of them might be gone for a while, especially if everything else is unplugged, the fan speed upped to ~2500–3000 (almost inaudible for most people over 19 or so), air conditioned room, etc. [To use a AMD chip in this generation of MBPs the chip itself has to replaced with a more robust, later, cooler revision and ideally the cooling system improved (better thermal compound better applied and additional holes for the airflow)] For an example of latent issues in the early stages [see this post.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244642/early-2011-macbook-pro-display-crash)

But most frustrating would be a common practice popularised on youtube and other sides: reflowing/baking the logic board. That is a failed AMD chip is heated to 120–200 degrees Celsius and thereafter shown off as a re-animated corpse. But only for a short time compared to the time it was running before with no apparent problems. This procedure has a kind of half-life until the problems come back, and worse that time, breaking even sooner than before and eventually failing completely with no amount of baking doing any good any more.

That means that a self-sourced OS is of only limited value to protect against a rogue seller. A GPU treated in this way is dying soon but likely not in the time it usually takes to make a quick test of basic function in a typical sales situation. This is a latent problem in my definition.

Nevertheless it is not really possible to protect yourself from a rebaked chip. But it is possible – in a limited way – to guard against someone showing off a GPU-switching Mac with only intel GPU active ([like certain hacks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859)):

- Boot your own OS. That is: macOS from an external drive. Then go into Apple Menu>About This Mac>System Report and check what is listed there. Since your own OS will contain the drivers but not the hacks: Manipulated to iGPU-only Macs will only list the IntelHD3000 chip there. (But also very likely hang on boot with your stick/drive) If you see trouble on boot in this configuration: reset the SMC/PRAM/NVRAM, reboot again and if there are immediately visible artefacts: then confront the seller!
- Boot your own OS. That is: try a LiveLinux like Ubuntu. Problems already manifest show up quicker there since even the basic acceleration there (without the proprietary drvers) stress the chip too much. Also check the hardware from your chosen Linux distribution.